# Excel cells formatting and round off VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel, number-formatting

How can I make this value

`167,155.30` into `167.16`
`13,839.15` into `13.84`

My code:

`xlWs.Cells(dgvRow.Index + 5, dgvColumn.Index + 4).NumberFormat = "#,###.00"`

Comment: Divide it by 1000, then round. This is just math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does *not* seem to be a problem with formatting but **rounding**.

After you read a number from your cell, divide it by `1000` and display it with `ToString("F2")`

```
Dim num As Double = Convert.ToDouble("167,155.30") 'change this to Excel cell data
Dim displayNum As String = (num/1000).ToString("F2")
'note the /1000
```

Then your `displayNum` will have value of `167.16`